# RTDB keepSynced - How does it work after the app is closed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

When using the keepSynced method, when the app is closed and reopened, does the library maintain the state of what was previously set as keepSynced as true?

We are not sure if we have to programmatically desynchronize database paths after marking a path as keepSynced as true.

Our data is changing roughly once a day, so what we needed to keep synchronized would change between user app sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a location from the Realtime Database synchronized, this means that the client will attach an empty listener to that particular location. This also means that the data in the app will be kept up to date with the online version of the database that exists on the server. But remember, this feature will work only if your users do have an internet connection.

If you haven't enabled persistence, all the data from that location will only be kept up to date in memory. If you've enabled persistence using:

```
Firebase.database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
```

This means that data will also be kept up to date on the local disk and will be available for offline use.

> if we have to programmatically desynchronize database paths after marking a path as keepSynced as true.

If you are referring to removing the listeners when listening to real-time updates, yes, you should always remove them according to the state of your app.